# How do I do this lamba statement as Linq To Sql?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, lambda

how can the `ThenBy` be translated to `Linq-To-Sql`, please?

```
var movies = _db.Movies.Orderby(c => c.Category).ThenBy(n => n.Name)

var movies = from m in _db.Movies
             orderby m.Category
             // What's the syntax for ThenBy?! 
             // thenby m.Name 
             select m;
```

When i try to do `thenby m.Name`, i get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to a simple comma separated list of expressions (which is translated to `ThenBy` method call), you can also specify the sorting order:

```
var q = from m in db.Movies
        orderby m.Category descending, m.Name ascending 
        select m

// Translates to:
db.Movies.OrderByDescending(...).ThenBy(...)
```

Another example:

```
var q = from m in db.Movies
        orderby m.Category, m.Name descending
        select m

// Translates to:
db.Movies.OrderBy(...).ThenByDescending(...)
```

The first element of the comma separated list is translated to either `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` (if you specify the `descending` keyword). Similarly, the next elements are translated to either `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending`. You can also write `ascending`, but this is the default option, so it behaves in exactly the same way as if you didn't use it.

Answer (score 6):

```
var movies = from m in _db.Movies
         orderby m.Category, m.Name
         select m;
```